# jacoco.exec coverage is not removing coverage of excluded files

Tags: java, spring-boot, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have added configuration with excluded files in jacoco maven plugin but coverage under jacoco.exec is not reflecting to exclude files

I already tried adding exclusion at level: coverage-check, coverage-report, post-integration-test as well as directly under plugin level. Exclude option is working only for index.html file but coverage under jacoco.exec is not reflecting to exclude files . One of example fo exclusion:

```
                        <id>coverage-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--<dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>-->
                            <rules>
                                <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                                    <!--<element>CLASS</element>-->
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*/com/xyz/*.class</exclude>
</excludes>
</rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

line coverage in index.html is coming as 64% but jacoco.exec shows coverage as 23% only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify the specific packages for the 'jacoco-check'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055625/how-to-specify-the-specific-packages-for-the-jacoco-check)

Comment: I added my answer here which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69352172/9813464

Answer (score 1):

Please carefully read https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html#rules :

`excludes` inside `rule` specifies name of `element`

So in case of commented-out

```
<!--<element>CLASS</element>-->
```

default value of `element` is `BUNDLE` and so excludes should specify names of `BUNDLE`s

In case of

```
<element>CLASS</element>
```

> `<exclude>**/*/com/xyz/*.class</exclude>`

won't work, because `excludes` is not about names of files - they are about names of classes and instead `/` they have `.` and don't have `.class` at the end.